# Fitted values starting from 0?

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm quite new to Python, was trying to build an ARIMA model following some guides online but somehow I run into two problems:

1. the fitted values start from near 0 and the residuals start from sky high
2. I get this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)` when running `fc, se, conf = model.fit().forecast(test.shape[0],alpha=0.05)`

Here's the code. I saw some other codes doing a model_fit = model.fit(disp=0) but when I try that I get `TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'`

```
# Build Model
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(train, order=(2, 1, 1)) 
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary()) 
fitted = model.fit()  

# Plot residual errors
residuals = model_fit.resid
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
fig.set_size_inches(14,4)
residuals.plot(title="Residuals", ax=ax[0])
residuals.plot(kind='kde', title='Density', ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
print(residuals.describe())

# Actual vs Fitted
train.plot(label='actual')
model_fit.fittedvalues.plot(label='fitted')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)
plt.show()

# Forecast
fc, se, conf = model.fit().forecast(test.shape[0],alpha=0.05)  # 95% conf
# Make as pandas series
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=test.index)
#lower_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 0], index=test.index)
#upper_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 1], index=test.index)
# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(train, label='training')
plt.plot(test, label='actual')
plt.plot(fc_series, label='forecast')
plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, lower_series, upper_series, 
                 color='k', alpha=.15)
plt.title('Forecast vs Actuals')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

These two images should illustrate the problem, the first shows residuals starting from sky high and the second shows the fitted starting from near zero.

Picture 1: Residuals

[image: Picture 1: Residuals]

Picture 2: Fit vs Actual

[image: Picture 2: Fit vs Actual]

Thanks a lot for helping a beginner out!

Comment: When you have d=1 the first residual is nonsense, and so should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kevin for the suggestion on the residual - that worked!

Also, on the `disp` error I realized it was the difference between
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model and
from statsmodels.tsa.arima**_**model

the _ is an older model where the code I was following was from. Another thread on this issue from https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7289

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

For the late comers, I think you may have used a statsmodel version different from the sample code. Check `statsmodels.__version__`, I think yours should be something older than 0.10. Mine is 0.13.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).